# Can two CloudKit call deadlock each other? How to fix?

Tags: ios, objective-c, deadlock, cloudkit

Inside a `performQuery` an other `performQuery` is being called. The `recordType` arguments are same for both, but the `predicate`s are different.

The second `performQuery` never returns, the App just runs and waits for CloudKit to respond.

The pseudo code is like this:

```
publicDatabase.performQuery(CKQuery(recordType: recordTypeSrc, predicate: predicate), inZoneWithID: nil, completionHandler: {records, error in

    if error == nil {

        //.. problem is not name collision or reusing the same parameter, coming codepart is called though other methods

        publicDatabase.performQuery(CKQuery(recordType: recordTypeSrc, predicate: predicate2), inZoneWithID: nil, completionHandler: {records, error in

            //THIS LINE WILL NEVER GET REACHED

            if error == nil {

            } else {
                println(error.localizedDescription)
            }
            dispatch_semaphore_signal(sema2)
        })
        dispatch_semaphore_wait(sema2, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER)

        //..

    } else {
        println(error.localizedDescription)
    }
    dispatch_semaphore_signal(sema)
})
dispatch_semaphore_wait(sema, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deadlock was fixed like this: Inner query moved after outer query. Both semaphore retained. Outer completion handler is finished before inner completion handler would start. From CloudKit returned records are stored in local variables.

```
var records: [AnyObject]! = []
publicDatabase.performQuery(CKQuery(recordType: recordTypeSrc, predicate: predicate), inZoneWithID: nil, completionHandler: {records2, error in

    if error == nil {
        records = records2
    } else {
        println(error.localizedDescription)
    }
    dispatch_semaphore_signal(sema)
})
dispatch_semaphore_wait(sema, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER)

//HERE I can use records

var records3: [AnyObject]! = []
publicDatabase.performQuery(CKQuery(recordType: recordTypeSrc, predicate: predicate2), inZoneWithID: nil, completionHandler: {records4, error in

    if error == nil {
        records3 = records4
    } else {
        println(error.localizedDescription)
    }
    dispatch_semaphore_signal(sema2)
})
dispatch_semaphore_wait(sema2, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER)

//HERE I can use records3 too
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a semaphore threading issue. You are reusing the sama parameter. The last dispatch_semaphore_signal must be moved to above inside the else. Then the first dispatch_semaphore_wait can be removed completely. So it will be like this:

```
publicDatabase.performQuery(CKQuery(recordType: recordTypeSrc, predicate: predicate), inZoneWithID: nil, completionHandler: {records, error in

    if error == nil {

        //.. problem is not name collision, it is nested though other blocks

        publicDatabase.performQuery(CKQuery(recordType: recordTypeSrc, predicate: predicate2), inZoneWithID: nil, completionHandler: {records, error in

            //THIS LINE WILL NEVER GET REACHED

            if error == nil {

            } else {
                println(error.localizedDescription)
            }
            dispatch_semaphore_signal(sema)
        })

        //..

    } else {
        println(error.localizedDescription)
        dispatch_semaphore_signal(sema)
    }
})
dispatch_semaphore_wait(sema, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER)
```

Comment: I use two distinct semaphore

Comment: ah, ok, you don't need 2 semaphore's you could use the structure that I mentioned above. It should not be a problem executing multiple queries after each other. I have done that before. Maybe try to execute your code without the semaphore? Then at least you should see some logging (if you have that)

Comment: I can not leave semaphore, outer query needs inner query return value, it seems although it is only a read operation, CloudKit locks table until closure is finished

Comment: first the outher query is executed and then the inner query. The outer query can not use data from the inner query. the inner query will only be executed when the outer query is finished. therefore it's enough to wait for the inner query to finish using only one semaphore. If you need data from both queries, then put that inside the response of the second query or below the bottom semaphore_wait